# Passing a subclass to a method with an abstract class parameter

Tags: java, inheritance

I've been trying to understand what is happening with this example, but haven't been able to so far. Can anyone help?

Say I have these two Abstract classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractBook<T extends AbstractPage> implements Serializable{
    public AbstractBook() {
    }

    public abstract void addPage(T var1);
}
```

and

```
public abstract class AbstractPage implements Serializable {
    public AbstractPage() {
    }
}
```

And classes that are extended like these:

```
public class Book extends AbstractBook {

    private ArrayList<Page> allPages;
    private String title;

    Book(String title){
       allPages = new ArrayList<Page>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPage(AbstractPage page) {
        this.allPages.add();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Page extends AbstractPage {

  private String content;

  public Page(String Content){
    this.content = Content;
  }

}
```

In the `Book` class there is a method called `addPage`. I can pass a `Page` class object to this method, however; I can't add that object to the `ArrayList<Page> allPages`.

Why exactly is that? I mean I think it is because the compiler expects type `AbstractPage` instead of `Page`. But why then I am capable of calling the method like `thisbook.addPage(pageObject)` ?

So In other words, it lets me pass a subclass object, but it doesn't let me do anything with that passed object.

And how do you get around this so that I can add that pageObject to the `ArrayList<Page> allPages` structure?

Comment: I imagine it's because not all AbstractPage's are Page's, you could try using an interface for this.

Comment: Usually an abstract class is a poor type for a parameter; try to rethink it in terms of interfaces.

Comment: @9000 I thought the same way. Do you think there is another way to override the `addPage` method? It doesn't allow me to just put Page type parameter  `<T extends AbstractPage>` sounds like it should, but I guess I was wrong. (I am not allowed to change anything in abstract classes)

Comment: _I can't add that object to ..._ `allPages`. That's because this line of code you posted doesn't compile: `this.allPages.add();`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by modifying your `Book` class:

```
public class Book extends AbstractBook<AbstractPage> {

  private ArrayList<AbstractPage> allPages;
  private String title;

  Book(String title){
    allPages = new ArrayList<AbstractPage>();
  }

  @Override
  public void addPage(AbstractPage page) {
    this.allPages.add(page);
  }
}
```

You should use the type parameter of `AbstractBook` when defining the class `Book`. The `ArrayList` has to bee of type `AbstractPage` if you want to insert elements of this type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `AbstractPage` to list of `Page`s, because `Page` is one level up in terms of inheritance from `AbstractPage`: `Object` <- `AbstractPage` <- `Page`. If you want to add `Page`s to your list, you have to extend `AbstractBook<Page>`:

```java
public class Book extends AbstractBook<Page> {

    private ArrayList<Page> allPages;
    private String title;

    Book(String title){
       allPages = new ArrayList<Page>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPage(Page page) {
        this.allPages.add();
    }
}
```